# Port forwarding EMR Zepplin through SSH

Tags: ssh, emr, amazon-emr

I'm trying to establish a secure connection to my emr server on AWS.

I have successfully connected through putty to it. However I would like to use zeppelin through the SSH tunnel.

Does the following look correct to forward the port 8890 from the EMR host to my local machines 8890 so that traffic is encrypted? Im on a windows machine.

[image]

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destination is in respect to the SSH Server. Providing Localhost:8890 will mean 8890 of the machine on which SSH server is running.

Comment: Hey Viresh - so if the SSH Server is the EMR Master Node then that is correct?